# Left pad hex list

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I change my code in Python 3:

```
v = b'\x8c\x00'
' '.join([hex(i) for i in v])
```

Such that '0x8c 0x0' becomes '8c 00'

/Barry

Comment: `[hex](i)` is not valid code. Do you mean `hex(i)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
v = b'\x8c\x00'
print(' '.join(['{:02x}'.format(i) for i in v]))
```

yields

```
8c 00
```

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming you are using Python 3.x.)

One option is to use `binascii.hexlify()` to convert to a hex string, and insert the spaces in a second step if needed:

```
s = binascii.hexlify(v)
s = b" ".join(s[i:i + 2] for i in range(0, len(s), 2))
```

This will set `s` to `b'8c00'` first and to `b'8c 00'` in the second step.  If you need `str` instead of `bytes`, you can use `s.decode("ascii")`.